# jquery for loop parsing variable in a eq()

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, class, for-loop

I am having a problem with JQuery at the moment where I am trying to parse a integer variable in a for loop in a eq() function. The problem I am having is when I try append the class ".episode-l" (needs to be a class as there are multiple of these and are displayed with a getjson) in a certain location with the eq() function but it wont display with a variable, I need it as a variable as i need to increment it each loop. There are other posts like this but I have looked at them and none of them work. Here is the code:

```
for( var i = 0; i < filmnamevar.length; i++)
{           
    $.getJSON('http://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movie?query='+ filmnamevar[i] +'&api_key=81c50c197b83129dd4fc387ca6c8c323',function(dataa){

        $('.episode-l').eq(i).append('<div class="rating">'+ dataa.results['0'].vote_average +'</div>');
        console.log(i);
    });
}
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Closures#Creating_closures_in_loops.3A_A_common_mistake

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a common problem associated with the usage of a closure in a loop.

Assuming `filimnamevar` is a array, since you are using jQuery you can use [$.each()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/)(instead of using an IIFE function as given in the below links but the principle behind the problem is the same)

```
$.each(filmnamevar, function (i, val) {
    $.getJSON('http://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movie?query=' + val + '&api_key=81c50c197b83129dd4fc387ca6c8c323', function (dataa) {

        $('.episode-l').eq(i).append('<div class="rating">' + dataa.results['0'].vote_average + '</div>');
        console.log(i);
    });
})
```

Read

- [Creating closures in loops: A common mistake](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Closures#Creating_closures_in_loops.3A_A_common_mistake)
- [Javascript closure inside loops - simple practical example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example)

Comment: I would have been confused forever at this one, so thank you so much.